# Replace string starting with specific char, until specific char

Tags: string, bash, macos

Globally in a file, I want to find all occurrences of strings starting with `.git#v` and replace the part of the string from the `v` until the next `"` with another string.

So, f.e. if I had `migrations.git#v1.1.1",` - I want to find it by `.git#v` and replace `v1.1.1` with `develop`. The point is that the version number will vary for the different occurrences, that's why I need to rely on finding these pieces by the `.git#v` part.

I've got this so far:

```
sed -i -- 's/.git#v/.git#develop/g' package.json
```

but I know this is quite not enough because it will only replace the whole `.git#v` with `develop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'migrations.git#v1.1.1"' |sed -r 's/\.git#v[^"]+"/\.git#develop/g'
migrations.git#develop
```

IF you do not wish to use `-r` : `+` sign needs to be taken care of.

```
sed 's/\.git#v[^"]\+"/\.git#develop/g'
migrations.git#develop
```

`awk` solution , using `gsub` :

```
echo 'migrations.git#v1.1.1"' |awk '{gsub(/.git#v[^"]+"/,".git#develop")}1'
migrations.git#develop
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to say I'm on OSX. `-r` is an illegal option for `sed`.

Comment: @Milkncookiez check update in answer for alternate approch.

Comment: I'd use `sed 's/\.git#v[^"]\+"/\.git#develop/g' package.json` but it would only print the contents of the file, w/o any actions performed on it.

Comment: did you tried -E option like  `sed -E 's/\.git#v[^"]+"/\.git#develop/g'` ?

Comment: Yes, that has the same effect. It prints out the changed contents of the file in the console, but the file itself isn't changed. And also, the last `"` is removed.

Comment: not good with OSX, if you wish you can try `awk` solution above in updated answer.

Comment: Hmm.. same thing happens. I could install `gnu-sed`, but I need to make this into a cross-platform (OSX / Linux) executable, so I'll have to use regular unix commands.

Comment: @Milkncookiez `echo 'migrations.git#v1.1.1"' | sed 's/\.git#v[^"]*/.git#develop/g'` should work with any `sed` version...